# Calculating Business Hours between Case Closed Date and Case Created Date

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a requirement where i need to calculate the business hours between Case closedDate and case CreatedDate without getting saturdays and sundays .
Can anyone help me with the formuale how to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually use the Calendar object, Holidays, BusinessHours model in SF setup?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_supporthours.htm&type=5
There's whole nice Apex class and `diff` method out of the box: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_businesshours.htm

If that's too much you could look into formula fields (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.formula_date_time_tipsheet.meta/formula_date_time_tipsheet/formula_examples_dates.htm, "Find the Number of Weekdays Between Two Dates")

---

Assuming you do actually use apex and have called BusinessHours.diff...

```
Long differenceInMiliseconds = 12340000; // from BusinessHours.diff()
String ret = DateTime.newInstance(differenceInMiliseconds).formatGmt('hh:mm:ss');
System.debug(ret); // 03:25:40
// 3 * 3600 + 25 * 60 + 40 = 10800 + 1500 + 40 = 12340, cool
```

Comment: I am getting Number Of Hours between the Case ClosedDate and CreatedDate
But I need them in the below format as HH:MM:SS

Comment: post what you have so far, what have you tried. We aren't a free coding service. You tagged it apex but I suspect you don't have actual code, just formula fields? If you do code - it's not rocket science to divide by 60 few times or use DateTime.format

Comment: I am getting Only Business Days. From This I need to Calculate Business Hours 
ROUND( 8 * (
( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( ClosedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) /
7) +
MIN(5,
MOD( DATEVALUE( ClosedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN( 1, 24 / 8 * ( MOD( ClosedDate - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 16:00:00' ), 1 ) ) )
)
)
-
( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) /
7) +
MIN( 5,
MOD( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) - DATE( 1996, 1, 1), 7 ) +
MIN( 1, 24 / 8 * ( MOD( CreatedDate - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 16:00:00' ), 1) ) )
)
)
),
0 )

Comment: Sorry, I'm too sober for this formula. You could try posting on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com, better chance of it being seen by admins and other low-code users. You tagged it with apex programming language so I gave you a built-in that can calculate it with few lines of code - but achieving same thing in formula fields might be tricky.