# Calculate case age in salesforce org

Tags: salesforce, case, salesforce-developer

How to calculate case age? Excluding weekends and Holidays?
if case is close calculate till close date or if case is open calculate till today.

it would be great if anyone will help me with step by step like i am new to this tech. thanks in advance

I tried using formula but could not do with that what should be the exact solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sample formula exists in documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385836&type=1 but it does only Monday-Friday, no holidays.

There's also a link about feature activation that can help in reports: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387290&type=1

A more proper thing would be to calculate it with apex, there's [a built-in function for that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) assuming you configured the calendar and holidays in setup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69723001/313628